# How to adjust vertical space before and after center environment

Tags: spacing, environments

It seems that there are vertical blank spaces before and after the `center` enviroment, as shown in the attached picture.

My question is: how to adjust these vertical blank spaces?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
  \begin{center}
    aaa\\bbb\\ccc
  \end{center}
\rule[\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{1pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, use `{\centering...\par}` to eliminate the added space.

Comment: Thank you @Steven. As `\centering` may lead to some odd and uncontrolable behavior, `center` enviroment seems to be better, except that how to adjust the extra vertical spaces before/after it.

Comment: I am not sure why you think "odd and uncontrollable behavior" may result.  The use of braces `{ }` before and after the `\centering...\par` is intended to limit the effect of `\centering` to the scope within the braces.

Comment: For your particular use case, I would also add a `\strut` before the `\par`.

Comment: Also, if you show the `\meaning` of `\center` (the environment), you will discover that it is just `\centering` inside of a `\trivlist`.

Comment: For example, `\centering` used immediatly after `\clearpage` would lost its centerline ability, in this case, an extra `\par` have to be added before `\centring` which introduces unwanted vertical space.

Comment: `\clearpage
  {\centering
    Aaa\\bbb\\ccc\strut
  \par}` does not lose its centerline ability.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with my code in `{centering ... \par}` which causes un-centerline.

Comment: as Steven says center is just centering with the addition of vertical display space. you want \centering here

Comment: And how to adjust this vertical display space if I intend to?

Answer (score 1):

I added a `\vspace{}` command inside the `center` environment at the top and buttom, which seems to have worked. You can make the space smaller by using negative values and make the space larger by using positive values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace{-4mm}
    aaa\\bbb\\ccc
    \vspace{-2mm}
  \end{center}
\rule[\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{1pt}
\end{document}
```

This code produces:

[image]

Using positive values `5mm` and `7mm`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I'd like to know if there are  default values for these vertical spaces in the `center` enviroment and where can I find them.

Comment: https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf
Page 621: `\def\center{\trivlist \centering\item\relax} \def\endcenter{\endtrivlist}`
Centering invokes the trivlist environment to handle vertical spacing before
and after. This is found on page 648. Beofre: `\parskip` (which is dependent on the documentclass) After: `\vskip \lastskip -\@outerparskip + \parskip`.

Comment: To find the documentation go to latex-project.org -> help -> documentation -> scroll down to "Source documentation" -> click on "The LaTeX2e Sources (1000+ pages)".

Comment: Thank you so much!! And what does `\item` do in the defination of `\center`?

Comment: I guess it is the same as `item` in `enumerate` and `itemize`, but without any point/ number. The `item` probably refers specificually (in this case) to eighter the text in the center environment or nothing (an empty list is after all a trivial list).